# I am getting an error saying I need to add a unique key to my DrawerItems - How can I do this?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I need to add a unique key to each of my Drawer items. I am abit confused as to how to do this? The code works but I still get the error.

This is my code:

```
 const drawer = (
    <div className="flex flex-col">
      <div className="drawer-container">
        <div className="menu-container mt-8">
          <List>
            <div>
              <DrawerItem
                name="Home"
                link="/home"
                icon="home"
                matchLinks={['home']}
              />
            </div>
            <div>
              <DrawerItem name="Profile" icon="people" link="/profile" matchLinks={['profile']} />
            </div>
            <div>
              <DrawerItem
                name="page 2"
                icon="page 2"
                link="/page-2"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="lg:mt-96 2xl:mt-4px">
              <DrawerItem
                name="Settings"
                icon="settings"
                link="/setting"
              />
            </div>
          </List>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component

Comment: Can you add the DrawerItem  module?

Comment: Try to add unique "key" property to each <DrawerItem> component

Comment: @MrBens can the key be anything?? eg: key={item}. If i say key={item} its says cannot find item

Comment: you can use one of your already unique attributes like "name"